# Remove all the punctuation from a dataframe, except some characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove all the punctuation from a dataframe, except the characters '<' and '>'

**I tried:**

```
def non_punct(df):

    df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace('[^\w\s]' | ~(<) | ~(>),' ')

    return df
```

**Output:**

```
    File "<ipython-input-292-ac8369672f62>", line 3
        df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.replace('[^\w\s]' | ~(<) | ~(>),' ')
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**My dataframe:**

```
       A          B                                    C
  French      house               Phone. <phone_numbers>
 English      house               email - <adresse_mail>
  French  apartment                      my name is Liam
  French      house                        Hello George!
 English  apartment   Ethan, my phone is <phone_numbers>
```

**Good output:**

```
       A          B                                    C
  French      house               Phone <phone_numbers>
 English      house               email  <adresse_mail>
  French  apartment                     my name is Liam
  French      house                        Hello George 
 English  apartment   Ethan my phone is <phone_numbers>
```

Comment: Could you please add desired output, because it looks like you are just missing quotes in your regex?

Comment: @zipa Done! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way with `string.punctuation`:

```
>>> import re
>>> import string

>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'a': ['abc', 'de.$&$*f(@)<', '<g>hij<k>'],
...     'b': [1234, 5678, 91011],
...     'c': ['me <me@gmail.com>', '123 West-End Lane', '<<xyz>>']
... })

>>> punc = string.punctuation.replace('<', '').replace('>', '')

>>> pat = re.compile(f'[{punc}]')
>>> df.replace(pat, '')
           a      b                 c
0        abc   1234   me <megmailcom>
1       def<   5678  123 WestEnd Lane
2  <g>hij<k>  91011           <<xyz>>
```

You should double-check that this constant is inclusive of what you want:

> String of ASCII characters which are considered punctuation characters
>   in the C locale.

Values:

```
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>> string.punctuation.replace('<', '').replace('>', '')
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;=?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

---

Notes:

- This solution uses an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-features) (Python 3.6+)
- It encloses those literal characters in a [character set](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to match any of them
- Note the difference between `df.replace()` and `df[my_column_name].str.replace()`.  The signature for `pd.DataFrame.replace()` is `DataFrame.replace(to_replace=None, value=None, inplace=False, limit=None, regex=False, method='pad')`, where `to_replace` can be a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to achieve your result with `re.sub`. Also, I think your regex is off, It should be `[[^\w\s^<^>]|_`. This matches everything that is not a number, integer, whitespace, < or >. You have to explicitly match the underscore because that is exempted in `\w`.

```
import re
re.sub('[^\w\s^<^>]|_', ' ', 'asdf.,:;/\><a b_?!"§$%&a')
>>> 'asdf      ><a b        a'
```

Just as a comparison:

```
re.sub('[^\w\s] | ~(<) | ~(>)', ' ', 'asdf.,:;/\><a b_?!"§$%&a')
>>> 'asdf.,:;/\\><a b_?!"§$%&a'

re.sub('[^\w\s^<^>]', ' ', 'asdf.,:;/\><a b_?!"§$%&a')
>>> 'asdf      ><a b_       a'
```

EDIT: Your error results from a misplaced quotation mark: it should be `'[^\w\s] | ~(<) | ~(>)'` and not `'[^\w\s]' | ~(<) | ~(>)`

EDIT 2: as pointed out by @Brad Solomon, `pd.Series.str.replace` does perfectly well with regex, so adding `[[^\w\s^<^>]|_` as the pattern to match in your statement should do the trick. Haven't tested that, though. @marin: If you happen to give this a try, leave me feedback so that I can update the post if needed.

Comment: You're right! Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I Should learn to read properly. Will edit my post to no longer state that

Answer (score 1):

In single line (aside from `import`) it would be:

```
import string
df['C'] = df['C'].str.translate(None, string.translate(string.punctuation, None, '<>'))
```